CRAN repos not loading
I am trying to update my R version on my linux server and I am not able to do it, getting the error below:
R                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'R':
  - Curl error (35): SSL connect error for https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/oracle/8/repodata/repomd.xml [OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to cloud.r-project.org:443 ]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'R': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
(base) [root@DRAGEN3 R-4.4.1]#

Even if I tried to download the tar file and install R, none of the CRAN repos are reachable on browser also.

Did you try installing through apt, yum or pacman depending on your OS? If you're installing from source, the link is https://cloud.r-project.org/src/base/.

What happens if you do ping cloud.r-project.org from the command line? If that works, then it's likely you need to check your firewall rules and see if they're interfering with the connection.
